# Scroll within a Flexible Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to be able to make a section of the page scrollable, which will be between two sections of fixed sizes, but I want this section to expand as much as possible.

The reason why I want this, if the device is very small, the scroll works, but if the device is large, the scroll is not necessary.

I am trying to place a SingleChildScrollView (), inside a Flexible (), so that it expands as much as possible.

I am trying this but an error occurs
[image]

The design is like this

[image: The design is like this]

Comment: Update my question, with a picture of what I try...

Comment: Did you try Expanded instead of Flexible? In my experience, Flutter is very picky with the type of sizing widget you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, you can do it with a ListView.builder

```
class UiMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const UiMenu({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 8,
            child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.equalizer_rounded,
                        size: 45,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        "Option ${index + 1}",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                      ),
                      trailing: Icon(
                        Icons.chevron_right,
                        size: 45,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Result]